# Retrieve and print data to textboxes from mysql DB using ajax (How to use it twice in the same php page)

Tags: php, html, mysql, json

Retrieve and print data to textboxes from MySQL DB using Ajax (How to use it twice in the same form.PHP)
while MySQL two tables has the same column 'name' used

Where names database table is:

```
guid       id        name

1          101       aaaa
2          102       bbbb
```

and course_names database table is:

```
id    course_id       name

1      win7         Windows 7
2      win8         Windows 8
```

code 1 form.PHP

```
<td></td>
<tr>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function getname(val) {
             $.ajax({
                url: 'getinsdata.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'prn='+val,
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(data){
                    var len = data.length;
                    if(len > 0){
                        var id = data[0]['id'];
                        var name = data[0]['name'];

                        document.getElementById('name').value = name;  
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
<td align="right">PRN</td>
<td><input type="text" id="prn" name="prn" tabindex="1" onblur="getname(this.value);" <?php if(isset($_GET['id'])) print('value="'.$row['prn'].'"'); ?> /><font color="Red">**</font></td>

<td align="right">Employee Name</td>
<td><input class="p7" id="name" type="text" name="name" tabindex="2" <?php if(isset($_GET['id'])) print('value="'.$row['name'].'"'); ?>Disabled /></td>
</tr>
```

getinsdata.php

```
include('config.php');
$id = $_POST['prn'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM names WHERE id='$id'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 

$users_arr = array();

while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $users_arr[] = array("id" => $id, "name" => $name);
}

// encoding array to json format
echo json_encode($users_arr);
exit;
```

second code at the same form.php

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getname2(val2) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'getinsdata2.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: 'course_guid='+val2,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:function(data){
                        var len = data.length;
                        if(len > 0){
                            var id = data[0]['id'];
                            var course_id = data[0]['course_id'];
                            var name2 = data[0]['name'];
                            document.getElementById('course_id').value = course_id;  
                            document.getElementById('name').value = name2;  
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    <td align="right">Course ID</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="course_guid" name="course_guid" tabindex="3" onblur="getname2(this.value);" <?php if(isset($_GET['id'])) print('value="'.$row['course_guid'].'"'); ?> /><font color="Red">**</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">Course Adress</td>
    <td><input class="p7" id="course_id" type="text" name="course_Addr"   tabindex="4"   <?php if(isset($_GET['id'])) print('value="'.$row['course_Addr'].'"'); ?>Disabled /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">Course name</td>
    <td><input class="p7" id='name' type="text" name="course_name"  tabindex="5" <?php if(isset($_GET['id'])) print('value="'.$row['course_name'].'"'); ?>Disabled /></td>
    </tr>
```

getinsdata2.php

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
    $id2 = $_POST['course_guid'];
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM courses_names WHERE id='$id2'";

    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2); 

    $users_arr2 = array();

    while( $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2) ){
        $id2 = $row2['id'];
        $course_id = $row2['course_id'];
        $name2 = $row2['name'];
        $users_arr2[] = array("id" => $id2, "course_id" => $course_id, "name" => $name2);
    }

    // encoding array to json format
    echo json_encode($users_arr2);
    exit;
?>
```

In this case php get confused on selecting the right data.

your kind help is needed.

Answer (score 0):

As workaround from my side I did the following

second code at the same form.php

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getname2(val2) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'getinsdata2.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: 'course_guid='+val2,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:function(data){
                        var len = data.length;
                        if(len > 0){
                            var id = data[0]['id'];
                            var course_id = data[0]['course_id'];
                            var name2 = data[0]['2'];
                            document.getElementById('course_id').value = course_id;  
                            document.getElementById('2').value = name2;  
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    <td align="right">Course ID</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="course_guid" name="course_guid" tabindex="3" onblur="getname2(this.value);" <?php if(isset($_GET['id'])) print('value="'.$row['course_guid'].'"'); ?> /><font color="Red">**</font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">Course Adress</td>
    <td><input class="p7" id="course_id" type="text" name="course_Addr"   tabindex="4"   <?php if(isset($_GET['id'])) print('value="'.$row['course_Addr'].'"'); ?>Disabled /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">Course name</td>
    <td><input class="p7" id='2' type="text" name="course_name"  tabindex="5" <?php if(isset($_GET['id'])) print('value="'.$row['course_name'].'"'); ?>Disabled /></td>
    </tr>
```

getinsdata2.php

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
    $id2 = $_POST['course_guid'];
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM courses_names WHERE id='$id2'";

    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql2); 

    $users_arr2 = array();

    while( $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2) ){
        $id2 = $row2['id']; // column 0
        $course_id = $row2['course_id']; // column 1
        $name2 = $row2['2']; // where 2 is column name sequence in MySQL Table
        $users_arr2[] = array("id" => $id2, "course_id" => $course_id, "2" => $name2);
    }

    // encoding array to json format
    echo json_encode($users_arr2);
    exit;
?>
```

Result
[image: Fix]